Stripe Payment Button Not Triggering on Mobile
I’m working on a SvelteKit project with Supabase and Stripe. On my pricing page, I’ve got buttons for users to pay and upgrade their plans. Everything works great on desktop when I click the button, it redirects to Stripe’s payment page like it’s supposed to.
But on mobile, nothing happens when I click the button. It doesn’t even try to open Stripe’s payment page.
What I’ve Tried:
Using  with on:click events.
Switching to  tags with href set to the Stripe URL.
Messing around with some DOM manipulation to try to manually navigate to the checkout URL.
No matter what I try, it still doesn’t work on mobile. I feel like I’m missing something simple here.
My Code:
Here’s the button component I’m using:
let checkoutUrl = '#';

async function createCheckoutSession() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('/api/create-checkout-session', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        priceId,
        paymentType,
      }),
    });

    const data = await response.json();

    if (data.url) {
      checkoutUrl = data.url;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Checkout error:', e);
  }
}

async function handleClick() {
  if (!isCurrentPlan) {
    await createCheckoutSession();
    if (checkoutUrl !== '#') {
      window.location.href = checkoutUrl;
    }
  }
}

And here's how im rendering the button in Sveltekit
<button
  class={`checkout-button ${className}`}
  class:disabled={isCurrentPlan}
  on:click={handleClick}
  disabled={isCurrentPlan || isLoading}
>
  <slot>
    {#if isLoading}
      Processing...
    {:else if isCurrentPlan}
      Current Plan
    {:else}
      {paymentType === "subscription"
        ? "Upgrade To Pro"
        : "Upgrade To Lifetime"}
    {/if}
  </slot>
</button>

Finally, here's how im using the component on the pricing page.
<CheckoutButton
  priceId={$page.data.priceIds.PRO_YEARLY}
  paymentType="subscription"
  class="upgrade-button btn-popout btn-text-large"
>
  Upgrade To Pro
</CheckoutButton>

What I Expected:
When I click the button on mobile, it should navigate to Stripe’s payment page, just like it does on desktop.
What’s Actually Happening:
On mobile, clicking the button does nothing. It’s like the click event isn’t being triggered or the URL navigation isn’t working.

I would start by adding this code:
window.addEventListener(
    `error`,
    e => alert(e.toString()),
)

And then try running it on the smartphone again. Debugging webpages on smartphones is a bit tedious, but you should be able to use that small piece of code to see if you have an uncaught error.

Thanks this helped me debug the problem, turns out the stripe API that i have wasn't passing the correct data for the button to work. Thanks again!
